# Repeated operations on same cell. Can this cursor procedure be optimized or replaced with a query?

Tags: sql-server, cursor, sql-server-2014

I have a table with over 1,000,000 records. I need to replace any names in the text fields with aliases to help deidentify the data. For this example, let's assume the table is `TemporaryTest` and has two fields: `Id` (the key field) and `IndexedXML` (the text field).

I have a second table, `AppellationSubstitution`, that has the following columns: `TextEntry` (a name needing replacement), `Length` (length of TextEntry), `Replacement` (the replacement name, which may be of a different length). That table has about 110,000 rows.

The first step I use is (the regex matches words in the text field--it looks a bit odd because of some odd characters that show up in this database):

```
SELECT id, 
       matchindex, 
       matchlength, 
       replacement  
FROM   TemporaryTest 
       CROSS APPLY
master.dbo.Regexmatches('([Xx]-)?[\w-[0-9üÿ_]]{2,}(-[\w-[0-9üÿ_]]{2,})?(''[\w-[0-9üÿ_]])?', [IndexedXML], 
master.dbo.Regexoptionenumeration(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) 
       INNER JOIN dbo.appellationsubstitution 
       ON match = textentry
       ORDER BY Id, MatchIndex DESC;--if replace in forward order, insertion point gets moved
```

This produces a table with over 100,000 rows, which the following shows a few lines:

```
Id matchindex matchlength replacement

99309 122 5 “Demarcus”
108639 106 5 “Demarcus”
109809 84 6 “Rehbein”
110373 89 7 “Reginald”
111156 105 5 “Demarcus”
112452 129 6 “Thie”
112896 113 6 “Diberardino”
112896 92 6 “Diberardino”
113503 119 3 “Rubin”
```

The full procedure I'm currently trying out is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE ReplaceCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT id, 
       matchindex, 
       matchlength, 
       replacement
FROM   TemporaryTest 
       CROSS APPLY
master.dbo.Regexmatches('([Xx]-)?[\w-[0-9üÿ_]]{2,}(-[\w-[0-9üÿ_]]{2,})?(''[\w-[0-9üÿ_]])?', [IndexedXML], 
master.dbo.Regexoptionenumeration(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) 
       INNER JOIN dbo.appellationsubstitution 
       ON match = textentry
       ORDER BY Id, MatchIndex DESC;--if replace in forward order, insertion point gets moved 
DECLARE @Rid int, @Rmi AS int, @Rml AS int, @Rrep AS nvarchar(255);
OPEN ReplaceCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ReplaceCursor INTO @Rid, @Rmi, @Rml, @Rrep;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TemporaryTest
    Set IndexedXML =  STUFF([IndexedXML],@Rmi+1,@Rml,@Rrep) 
        WHERE Id = @Rid;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ReplaceCursor INTO @Rid, @Rmi, @Rml, @Rrep;
END;
CLOSE ReplaceCursor;
DEALLOCATE ReplaceCursor;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This works, but takes a very long time to run (over an hour and not yet completed), and IndexedXML is one of the smallest text fields I have in the production database.

I resorted to using a cursor as I didn't know any other way to manage sequential `STUFF` calls on the same cell, where subsequent `STUFF` calls use the result of the previous ones.

Am I taking the right course with this, or is there a faster/cleaner way of achieving this?

Comment: Probably best posted on codereview.stackexchange.com